# Monolingual Italian learner's dictionaries with small defining vocabulary

Tags: resources

Most modern English learner's dictionary use [controlled defining vocabulary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defining_vocabulary) for defining lemmas. Which Italian learner's dictionaries incorporate controlled defining vocabulary?

Answer (score 5):

The only monolingual Italian learner's dictionary I have found is [*Dizionario italiano per stranieri*](http://www.giunti.it/libri/linguistica/dizionario-italiano-per-stranieri2/), published by Giunti Demetra at its series *Scuola d'italiano*. I don't have this dictionary, but I have seen it in an Italian bookstore, so I could have a look. The definitions seem quite easy to understand, so I think it can be a good resource for an intermediate Italian learner. This dictionary is quite small and light enough to be carried out easily.

Maybe this is not a complete answer to the OP question because I don't know if they have really used a controlled defining vocabulary, but this is the only thing similar to what it's asked I've been able to find.